# markup://force:scopedSlds is not visible

Tags: lightning-aura-components

when i building visual force page with Lightning Component i see one console debug log.

> WARNING: Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'body' of
>   component 'markup://force:scopedSlds {3:0}' is not visible to
>   'markup://force:scopedSlds {3:0}'.

please let me know the why i am getting this issue.

Comment: try enable/disable locker service

Comment: where can i find the locker service in the system?

Comment: i tried the same way but still same issue.