# Javascript warning when a lightning component is loaded

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, error

I developed a lightning application embedded in a visualforce page.This lightning app works very well.

But since the Winter17', I've got the following javascript warning :

`WARNING: Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'body' of component 'markup://force:scopedSlds {3:0}' is not visible to 'markup://force:scopedSlds {3:0}'.`

I don't find any "force:scopedSlds" markup in the lightning components used for the app.

Why this error is raised and how can I fix it ?

I hope this error will not become a problem when the Locker Service will be activated !

below the visualforce page :

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <div id="lightning">
    </div>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:LA01_MultiCriteriaSearch", function() {
            runAfterGlobalsLoaded(function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:LC04_MCS", {}, "lightning");
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

below the lightning application (c:LA01_MultiCriteriaSearch) :

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:LC04_MCS"/>
</aura:application>
```

below the lightning component (c:LC04_MCS) :

```
<aura:component >
    <div id="hiddenTitle" style="display:none">{!$Label.c.MCS_Title}</div>
</aura:component>
```

Many thanks for your help

Julien

Comment: I had the same error and didn't find an answer

Comment: Also unanswered: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141926, the exact same error. The problem is that we can't diagnose the problem without some sample code that reproduces the error reliably. Can you post a trimmed down version of your code that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Known issue at the intersection of Access Checks and LO that is being fixed very soon - tracked by salesforce bug W-3428353 if oyu want to reference this in any communications with Salesforce. Please note that access checks have nothing to do with locker service - they are completely independent parts of our security and supportability architecture.